# Android FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation Synchronously

Tags: java, android, google-location-services

I need to convert async FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation call to the sync one. I'm not a big expert in Java and I'm not sure I've did it right.

I want to connect to `GoogleApiClient` and then block calling thread until location information or error is received. Timeout more than 10 seconds should be treated as an error.

Will it work this way or `onConnected` will be called on main thread as well and it will be locked at that moment?

I also noticed that `lock.wait(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10));` continues instantly in regular runs, but in step-by-step debugging it does wait 10 seconds as intended.

```
public class SyncLocationService implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    public GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    public SyncLocationService(Context context) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    private final Object lock = new Object();
    public android.location.Location mLocation;

    @Override
    public android.location.Location lastLocation() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        synchronized (lock) {
            try {
                lock.wait(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.i("NativeLocationService", "InterruptedException");
            }
        }
        return mLocation;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        try {
            mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.i("NativeLocationService", "SecurityException");
        } finally {
            synchronized (lock) {
                lock.notify();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I'm trying to rewrite similar iOS code which does it's job using semaphore.

```
var semaphore: DispatchSemaphore!
var location: CLLocation!

func lastLocation() -> location? {
    self.semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    _ = self.semaphore!.wait(timeout: .now() + 10)  // seconds
    self.semaphore = nil
    return self.location
}

// MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let semaphore = self.semaphore else {
        return
    }
    guard let first = locations.first else {
        return
    }
    self.location = first
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    semaphore.signal()
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36740758/how-to-return-value-on-googleapiclient-onconnected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GoogleApiClient.blockingConnect()` to wait until the connection is established, then call `FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation()`.